# how to create a button on click of another button in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a button and now i want that when i click this button and then this click creates one more button on the same page. Please tell me in detail how it should be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a placeholder, on click, you add new control button on that placeholder.

Comment: You can go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743083/asp-net-dynamically-created-button) or http://shahed-kazi.blogspot.in/2009/07/dynamically-add-button-control-to.html

Comment: please explain your ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to do it.

in aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMain" Text="Create New Button" runat="server" 
        onclick="btnMain_Click" />
```

in aspx.cs

```
private static int count=0;

protected void btnMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnNew = new Button();
    btnNew.ID = "btnNew_" + count;
    btnNew.Text = "New Button_" + count;
    Form.Controls.Add(btnNew);
    count++;
}
```

you can set any container control id in place of `this` to add the button inside that container. You can also set position, height, width etc of the button here. Hope it helps :)

Comment: where i should use this code in .aspx.cs file

Comment: @user2106115 : you can write it in your existing button's click event

Comment: thanks buddy...it solved my one problem. Now i want to persist the buttons means when i click "btnMain" then "New Button" is created but i want when again i click "btnMain" then one more button is created.

Comment: Avishek: i want new button with the existing button. but do not want to increment the count.

Comment: @user2106115 : Actually, here you will have new buttons each time, but if you dont reposition them, they will be visible over the previous. you can write code according to how you want to reposition new buttons.

Comment: @user2106115 : show some efforts from your end too..

Comment: @user2106115: you should upvote useful answers, and mark the answer that best solves your question as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use  `page_load` or `page_init`  event.

```
protected void Page_Load()// it can be any event button click also
{
  Button ButtonChange = new Button();

  ButtonChange.Text = "Change";
  ButtonChange.ID = "change_" + i.ToString();
  ButtonChange.Font.Size = FontUnit.Point(7);
  ButtonChange.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
  ButtonChange.Click += new EventHandler(test);
}
```

Read MSDN article - [How to: Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx)